# specs2-embedmongo unresolved dependency with Scala 2.10.1 and Play 2.1.1

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.1, scala-2.10, specs2

I'm within a Play 2.1.1, scala 2.10.1 environment using the latest [Salat](https://github.com/novus/salat/) build

I'm trying to get the [specs2-embedmongo](https://github.com/athieriot/specs2-embedmongo) dependency as described in their README.md: adding the following line to my Build.scala:

```
"com.github.athieriot" %% "specs2-embedmongo" % "0.5"
```

I also added, as indicated, the line

```
"de.flapdoodle.embed" % "de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo" % "1.31"
```

But when running play dependencies I get this output:

```
[warn]  module not found: com.github.athieriot#specs2-embedmongo_2.10;0.5       
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /usr/local/Cellar/play/2.1.1/libexec/repository/local/com.github.athieriot/specs2-embedmongo_2.10/0.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/github/athieriot/specs2-embedmongo_2.10/0.5/specs2-embedmongo_2.10-0.5.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Snapshots Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/com/github/athieriot/specs2-embedmongo_2.10/0.5/specs2-embedmongo_2.10-0.5.pom
[warn] ==== sonatype-snapshots: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/athieriot/specs2-embedmongo_2.10/0.5/specs2-embedmongo_2.10-0.5.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/athieriot/specs2-embedmongo_2.10/0.5/specs2-embedmongo_2.10-0.5.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::                       
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.athieriot#specs2-embedmongo_2.10;0.5: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.athieriot#specs2-embedmongo_2.10;0.5: not found
```

Is there a way to make this work with my current setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am currently working at compiling the library against Scala 2.10 while keeping the 2.9 compatibility. Need to clean up some other dependencies for that :)

Comment: Thanks, that totally did it :)

I just updated my Build.scala with the new data and it went all good.

Just have to update those dependency lines in the build file to:

`"com.github.athieriot" %% "specs2-embedmongo" % "0.5.1",
"de.flapdoodle.embed" % "de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo" % "1.33"`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the lib has not been compiled against Scala 2.10. You could try using [the previous version](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/github/athieriot/specs2-embedmongo_2.9.1/0.5/):

```
"com.github.athieriot" % "specs2-embedmongo_2.9.1" % "0.5"
```

Comment: I tried that but the play dependency-resolving mechanism either ignored my _2.9.1 and overrode it with _2.10.1 or I was missing something else. Luckily the project author just jumped in and published an updated release for scala 2.10.X

Comment: That's a far better solution :-)